# Input buttons not working in Firefox, working in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have an input button like so:

```
<input value="submit" type="text" onclick="doThing"/>
```

Is there any reason why this shouldn't be working in Firefox? I know Firefox functions work differently than in Chrome sometimes, but I'm not sure when this is the case.. I get no console errors in Firefox, annoyingly. The `doThing` function is not getting fired at all.

Any documentation about why this functions differently in Firefox? Or is this a more obscure bug? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That works just fine in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/9men7rnx/ (although global variables are almost always a bad idea). There's something going on *elsewhere*, in code you haven't shown.

Comment: if that works in chrome, then it will work in firefox ... but ... what is `addButton` variable?

Comment: ditto on the other comments, what is `addButton` exactly?  One FireFox gotya to check for is a global `event`, which will work for Chrome but break for FireFox.

Comment: Hmm alright, I guess the error is somewhere else in my very long js file, if firefox has no issues with this code. I'll poke around a bit more, thanks for the help.

Comment: addButton is just an input, it's found fine on both firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution! Bit of a Firefox quirk. The issue was *not* with the event listener, it was that somewhere else in my code I had to set the `disabled` value of my `input` to `true` in order to prevent multiple button clicks while my database was updating. In Chrome, when you refresh the page, the value of `disabled` is reset back to `false`,  but in *Firefox* there is a feature where it remembers the values of `input` fields.

Setting `autocomplete="off"` to my `<input/>` DOM element did the trick. It now works as intended in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Nice one. If you can edit the question to show that (while still keeping it a question), that'd be great, this will be useful to others in the future.

Comment: Done! I'll leave this up for people to see in the future.

Comment: That's not what I meant, the "keeping it a question" was important. Details here: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Alright I edited my question, is that more like how it should be? I never really answer my own stuff so!